# How to superimpose broken line plot over bar plot with uneven number data points along x axis (date)?

Tags: ggplot2, plot, data-visualization, geom-bar

I am trying to plot these one graph to show change of length at three different sites over time as temperature increases.

I shortened the temperature data frame to match the length data to create this plot: [Length/Temperature vs Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMkAN.jpg)

with this set of data:

```
structure(list(month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", 
"Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), site = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("port", "bluff", "palme"), class = "factor"), 
    mean = c(15.4066666666667, 14.7866666666667, 0, 38.3066666666667, 
    40.31, 52.06, 93.6266666666667, 84.6233333333333, 91.1083333333333, 
    51.6, 78.2766666666667, 96.9466666666667, 15.9633333333333, 
    59.1333333333333, 42.3233333333333, 10.3033333333333, 0.1, 
    0.1), sd = c(6.10053323465469, 5.62921770355553, 0, 14.1369211722314, 
    18.7262925984499, 18.0693224497518, 34.0724297822208, 43.6832697662534, 
    45.0430332232857, 26.4636380327995, 36.7493624934932, 44.660549074974, 
    6.0898719387098, 18.5524853495072, 16.3840478206244, 5.80234692905013, 
    0, 0), n = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), se = c(1.11379988847678, 
    1.02774983911493, 0, 2.58103687323451, 3.41893762487101, 
    3.29899183485452, 6.22074612691106, 7.9754374121868, 8.22369511828274, 
    4.83157716807198, 6.70948493720683, 8.15386338630991, 1.11185341104969, 
    3.38720490790306, 2.99130419153311, 1.05935876650386, 0, 
    0), tmp = c(18.893625, 18.893625, 18.893625, 19.7045148809524, 
    19.7045148809524, 19.7045148809524, 20.6929475806452, 20.6929475806452, 
    20.6929475806452, 23.8039069444444, 23.8039069444444, 23.8039069444444, 
    25.7307553763441, 25.7307553763441, 25.7307553763441, 28.3008958333333, 
    28.3008958333333, 28.3008958333333)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(7L, 
8L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
10L, 11L, 12L))
```

Plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df3, aes(x=month, y=mean)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=site), stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_line(aes(x=month, y=tmp*3, group=1), size=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./3, name = "Temperature"))
```

But I would like to produce a plot with the complete temperature data set that is much longer than the length data set, hence to superimpose the two plots below:

[Length vs Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbJQe.jpg)

```
structure(list(month = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", 
"Nov", "Dec"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), site = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("port", "bluff", "palme"), class = "factor"), 
    mean = c(15.4066666666667, 14.7866666666667, 0, 38.3066666666667, 
    40.31, 52.06, 93.6266666666667, 84.6233333333333, 91.1083333333333, 
    51.6, 78.2766666666667, 96.9466666666667, 15.9633333333333, 
    59.1333333333333, 42.3233333333333, 10.3033333333333, 0.1, 
    0.1), sd = c(6.10053323465469, 5.62921770355553, 0, 14.1369211722314, 
    18.7262925984499, 18.0693224497518, 34.0724297822208, 43.6832697662534, 
    45.0430332232857, 26.4636380327995, 36.7493624934932, 44.660549074974, 
    6.0898719387098, 18.5524853495072, 16.3840478206244, 5.80234692905013, 
    0, 0), n = c(30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
    30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), se = c(1.11379988847678, 
    1.02774983911493, 0, 2.58103687323451, 3.41893762487101, 
    3.29899183485452, 6.22074612691106, 7.9754374121868, 8.22369511828274, 
    4.83157716807198, 6.70948493720683, 8.15386338630991, 1.11185341104969, 
    3.38720490790306, 2.99130419153311, 1.05935876650386, 0, 
    0)), row.names = c(7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 10L, 11L, 12L), class = "data.frame")
```

[Temperature vs Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryiwK.jpg)

```
structure(list(month = structure(c(17927, 17928, 17929, 17930, 
17931, 17932, 17933, 17934, 17935, 17936, 17937, 17938, 17939, 
17940, 17941, 17942, 17943, 17944, 17945, 17946, 17947, 17948, 
17949, 17950, 17951, 17952, 17953, 17954, 17955, 17956, 17957, 
17958, 17959, 17960, 17961, 17962, 17963, 17964, 17965, 17966, 
17967, 17968, 17969, 17970, 17971, 17972, 17973, 17974, 17975, 
17976, 17977, 17978, 17979, 17980, 17981, 17982, 17983, 17984, 
17985, 17986, 17987, 17988, 17989, 17990, 17991, 17992, 17993, 
17994, 17995, 17996, 17997, 17998, 17999, 18000, 18001, 18002, 
18003, 18004, 18005, 18006, 18007, 18008, 18009, 18010, 18011, 
18012, 18013, 18014, 18015, 18016, 18017, 18018, 18019, 18020, 
18021, 18022, 18023, 18024, 18025, 18026, 18027, 18028, 18029, 
18030, 18031, 18032, 18033, 18034, 18035, 18036, 18037, 18038, 
18039, 18040, 18041, 18042, 18043, 18044, 18045, 18046, 18047, 
18048, 18049, 18050, 18051, 18052, 18053, 18054, 18055, 18056, 
18057, 18058, 18059, 18060, 18061, 18062, 18063, 18064, 18065, 
18066, 18067, 18068, 18069, 18070, 18071, 18072, 18073, 18074, 
18075, 18076, 18077, 18078, 18079, 18080, 18081, 18082, 18083, 
18084), class = "Date"), tmp = c(18.893625, 18.5962083333333, 
18.6715416666667, 18.9369583333333, 19.3453333333333, 19.274, 
19.5038333333333, 19.6745833333333, 19.6940833333333, 19.8091666666667, 
19.706125, 19.40075, 19.46825, 19.6822083333333, 19.8845416666667, 
19.8647916666667, 20.1585, 20.1541666666667, 19.6780416666667, 
19.8689583333333, 20.44425, 20.551375, 20.29725, 19.876625, 19.6822083333333, 
19.428375, 19.7496666666667, 19.9916666666667, 20.3329583333333, 
20.6546666666667, 20.328875, 20.5115833333333, 20.2219583333333, 
20.2930833333333, 20.4754583333333, 20.0629166666667, 19.8211666666667, 
19.7100416666667, 19.4284583333333, 19.6745, 20.1306666666667, 
20.301375, 20.01925, 19.7935416666667, 19.828875, 20.015375, 
20.0948333333333, 20.7105416666667, 21.1350833333333, 21.613875, 
22.1526666666667, 21.5527916666667, 20.9920833333333, 21.0596666666667, 
21.3459166666667, 21.4136666666667, 21.7238333333333, 22.4411666666667, 
22.0822916666667, 21.8911666666667, 21.5847916666667, 21.7676666666667, 
22.0030833333333, 21.9430833333333, 22.4825416666667, 23.0897083333333, 
23.5414583333333, 23.82, 24.0025833333333, 23.98625, 24.5325416666667, 
23.6770416666667, 23.136, 23.3080416666667, 23.1600833333333, 
22.7844583333333, 23.293375, 23.220125, 23.1320833333333, 23.0760833333333, 
23.7297916666667, 24.1209166666667, 24.9144583333333, 25.6327083333333, 
26.0205833333333, 26.126, 25.4773333333333, 25.1097916666667, 
25.6192916666667, 25.8253333333333, 25.7808333333333, 25.137125, 
25.0000416666667, 24.7380416666667, 24.4359166666667, 24.1663333333333, 
24.110125, 23.913625, 24.0101666666667, 24.3034583333333, 24.6014583333333, 
24.9077916666667, 25.0850833333333, 25.6234583333333, 25.9030416666667, 
26.968125, 26.897875, 27.5782916666667, 27.9786666666667, 27.61375, 
26.67575, 26.3882083333333, 26.0404166666667, 25.8984166666667, 
26.2809583333333, 26.1988333333333, 26.3817916666667, 26.46325, 
26.382, 26.0689166666667, 26.1216666666667, 26.6195, 26.859625, 
27.0225833333333, 27.2107083333333, 27.810125, 28.0363333333333, 
28.48275, 28.514375, 28.3447916666667, 28.0068333333333, 27.5096666666667, 
27.5627083333333, 27.0342083333333, 27.6620416666667, 27.9710833333333, 
27.953875, 27.936625, 28.21675, 28.439875, 29.0535833333333, 
29.439625, 29.6357083333333, 29.4480833333333, 29.015625, 28.4232916666667, 
28.386125, 28.8215416666667, 29.5276666666667, 29.602625, 30.4785416666667, 
29.8260416666667, 29.632625, 29.2770416666667, 29.3150416666667, 
29.6074583333333, 29.8493333333333, 29.778125), lgt = c(147.29012345679, 
11.8685956790123, 13.272299382716, 39.9496913580247, 99.766049382716, 
39.0691358024691, 25.5725308641975, 25.8137345679012, 8.34699074074074, 
3.13125, 2.07638888888889, 2.64945987654321, 10.3154320987654, 
15.0579475308642, 17.3253086419753, 5.01666666666667, 9.97484567901235, 
4.50987654320988, 0.490046296296296, 10.1826388888889, 84.2596450617284, 
24.7587191358025, 18.7372685185185, 0.431944444444444, 3.09814814814815, 
2.27561728395062, 1.17939814814815, 2.3420524691358, 14.7756172839506, 
5.03317901234568, 2.97345679012346, 10.9051697530864, 9.20262345679012, 
5.7971450617284, 2.7158950617284, 1.27893518518519, 2.15941358024691, 
1.35378086419753, 7.41674382716049, 15.3153549382716, 45.1071759259259, 
8.91180555555556, 0.847145061728395, 2.97337962962963, 5.51496913580247, 
6.80239197530864, 9.55956790123457, 19.1108796296296, 12.7988425925926, 
100.853858024691, 103.503472222222, 1.48672839506173, 1.52824074074074, 
7.30887345679012, 12.8653549382716, 8.03966049382716, 14.7921296296296, 
9.89174382716049, 3.88703703703704, 3.20594135802469, 3.16442901234568, 
6.14606481481481, 13.2888888888889, 10.797299382716, 93.5950617283951, 
67.7730709876543, 140.919984567901, 58.2300925925926, 39.8996913580247, 
34.9829475308642, 13.9283179012346, 5.21597222222222, 2.43371913580247, 
4.75910493827161, 6.20424382716049, 5.37368827160494, 31.4861882716049, 
8.70424382716049, 8.67098765432099, 5.43179012345679, 70.7297067901235, 
58.6121141975309, 55.7964506172839, 86.9338734567901, 18.9948302469136, 
19.418287037037, 9.50162037037037, 22.1922839506173, 25.4814043209877, 
10.3818672839506, 54.5672067901235, 14.6177469135802, 38.5707561728395, 
35.9960648148148, 6.78557098765432, 15.3651234567901, 11.5861111111111, 
13.6625, 57.0010030864198, 73.3876543209877, 89.4920524691358, 
124.690817901235, 29.2520833333333, 166.451080246914, 101.327237654321, 
252.703935185185, 280.303240740741, 515.025694444444, 523.862731481481, 
107.548225308642, 74.7662037037037, 264.074228395062, 16.6194444444444, 
26.8019290123457, 116.119598765432, 38.2054012345679, 47.7068672839506, 
53.346450617284, 17.9067901234568, 53.8114969135802, 60.1318672839506, 
191.243055555556, 164.881172839506, 99.0101080246914, 78.977237654321, 
163.701697530864, 139.366666666667, 107.556558641975, 4.65941358024691, 
0, 0, 0, 0.00833333333333333, 0.00833333333333333, 0.0498456790123457, 
0.0166666666666667, 0.00833333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.157793209876543, 
62.9890432098765, 16.3951388888889, 33.5790895061728, 52.6984567901235, 
50.3315586419753, 54.1604938271605, 66.2529320987654, 103.378703703704, 
123.984799382716, 37.2088734567901, 6.13788580246914, 1.47013888888889, 
28.2389660493827, 111.103240740741, 66.1949074074074)), row.names = c(NA, 
-158L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I wonder if there's any way I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your length versus time data.frame is named `lvt` and the temperature versus time is named `tvt`, we first convert every date to a date

```
# Assuming lvt$month is a factor beginning at 1 = january, 12 = december
# We'll pseudocenter the month around the 15th
lvt$month2 <- as.Date(ISOdate(2019, as.numeric(lvt$month), 15))
```

Then once we'll have both x-axes in date format, we can plot the data:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = lvt, aes(month2, mean, fill = site), 
           position = "dodge",
           colour = "black") +
  geom_line(data = tvt, aes(month, tmp*3), size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./3, name = "Temperature"))
```

Which looks like the following:

[image]

Note that it is a bit of a weird plot, because essentially you're mixing ordered categorical data with continuous data. For example `tvt` starts at January 31st, so it looks like it actually starts in Februari. Furthermore the distances between the groups of bars aren't constant because February for example is a shorter month.

Comment: I tried to plot the error bars for length to the plot that you ultimately created (which is exactly how I envisioned it), but all the error bars aligned to the 15th of each month as you've psuedocentered. Is there a way to work around it?

Comment: Maybe it would help if you would dodge the position of errorbars, like so:   `geom_errorbar(data = lvt, aes(x = month2, ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd),               position = "dodge2")`. For me that gave decent looking errorbars.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I previously used `position = position_dodge`, which didn't work for me. I wonder what's the difference? Thank you again.

Comment: I got there by trial and error, so I don't know exactly, but the documentation seems to suggest that dodge2 can have variable widths.

Comment: I see. Thank you for figuring it out anyways!